# How to initialize joomla modal through js

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api, modal

I'm customizing a view in my component, I have tabs, each tab contains a modal, but when adding a new tab using js, I don't know how to initialize the new tab's modal via js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, I found it possible to use `Joomla.initialiseModal( document.getElementById(YOUR_MODAL_ID) )` to initialize the modal